# Grails 3 JMS Error during sending messages

Tags: jms, grails3

Due to issue https://github.com/gpc/jms/issues/27 I have add to application.yml

```
jms:
containers:
    standard:
        connectionFactoryBean: jmsConnectionFactory

adapters:
    standard:
        messageConverterBean: standardJmsMessageConverter
        persistenceInterceptorBean: persistenceInterceptor
```

Application starts, but during sending message application get error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'standardJmsTemplate' is defined at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:704)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory$getBean$3.call(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   grails.plugin.jms.JmsService.normalizeServiceCtx(JmsService.groovy:381)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1971.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
>   at grails.plugin.jms.JmsService.send(JmsService.groovy:147) at
>   grails.plugin.jms.JmsService.send(JmsService.groovy) at
>   grails.plugin.jms.JmsService$send.call(Unknown Source)

Grails 3.1.14 
org.grails.plugins:jms:2.0.0.RC1

I hope, the error possible to solve by configureation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Idea how it works, but fixed by additional lines in application.yml (Just copied from plugin code)

```
jms:
    templates:
        standard:
            connectionFactoryBean: jmsConnectionFactory
            messageConverterBean: standardJmsMessageConverter
```